# Counter is not increasing python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm making a simple python app to make my skill good. so I'm creating an app **Guess the number** but there is a problem with counter code is below it doesn't update the value

```
import random

def guess_the_number():
    counter = 0
    rand = random.randint(0, 5)
    a = int(input('enter the number between 0 to 5'))
    if a==rand:
        counter = counter + 1
        print('your total points are: ' + str(counter))
        print('Do you want to play again PRESS Y for yes and N for No')
        yn = input('enter Y or N')
        if (yn == 'Y' or yn == 'y'):
            guess_the_number()
        elif (yn == 'N' or yn == 'n'):
            print('bye')
            return
    elif a!=rand:
        counter = counter - 1
        print('your total points are: ' + str(counter))
        print('Do you want to play again PRESS Y for yes and N for No')
        yn = input('enter Y or N')
        if (yn == 'Y' or yn == 'y'):
            guess_the_number()
        elif (yn == 'N' or yn == 'n'):
            print('bye')
            return

        else:
            print('ah bad words')
    else:
        print('not include')

guess_the_number()
```

Comment: It does update the value, but then you _call_ a new version of the function, which does not see the previous version.  You should try a loop (while True:) rather than recursion.

Comment: Also, the lase *else* makes no sense.

Comment: `counter` is a variable local to the scope of the `guess_the_number` function, meaning that when you call `guess_the_number` again, a new `counter` is created for each function call, and is kept track of separately for each function call. Instead, either use a global variable, or put it in a class.

Comment: not related to your error or anything, just a small comment on the code: you can use `yn.lower()=='y'` instead of `yn=='Y' or yn=='y'`

Comment: I recommend learning how to use loops in python: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_while_loops.asp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should define `counter` outside of the function.
Each call to `guess_the_number()` resets the `counter = 0` variable.

Therefore; (remember to include `counter` to function calls `guess_the_number(counter)`)

```
import random;
    
counter = 0    
def guess_the_number(counter):
    
    rand = random.randint(0, 5)
    a = int(input('enter the number between 0 to 5: '))
    if a==rand:
        counter = counter + 1
        print('your total points are: ' + str(counter))
        print('Do you want to play again PRESS Y for yes and N for No: ')
        yn = input('enter Y or N: ')
        if (yn == 'Y' or yn == 'y'):
            guess_the_number(counter)
        elif (yn == 'N' or yn == 'n'):
            print('bye')
            return
    elif a!=rand:
        counter = counter - 1
        print('your total points are: ' + str(counter))
        print('Do you want to play again PRESS Y for yes and N for No: ')
        yn = input('enter Y or N: ')
        if (yn == 'Y' or yn == 'y'):
            guess_the_number(counter)
        elif (yn == 'N' or yn == 'n'):
            print('bye')
            return

        else:
            print('ah bad words')
    else:
        print('not include')

guess_the_number(counter)
```